# How to store hashed passwords in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, bcrypt

so i want to save a user object in firestore, it's my first time working with firestore, so i use Bcrypt to encode the password than i save the object in firestore but it doesn't seem to be able to save it

**This is my code**

```
 * createUser
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {string} password
 * @param {string} name
 */
const createUser = async (email, password, name) => {
  const user = await getUser(email);
  if (user) throw new Error('User account already exists');

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (hashedPassword) => {
      db.collection('users')
        .doc(email)
        .set({ hashedPassword, email, name });
    });
  });
};
```

and am getting this error

```
        throw new Error(validate_1.customObjectMessage(arg, value, path));
        ^

Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object (found in field "hashedPassword").
    at Object.validateUserInput (/home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:301:15)
    at validateDocumentData (/home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:620:22)
    at WriteBatch.set (/home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:234:9)
    at DocumentReference.set (/home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:340:14)
    at /home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/src/firestore/index.js:54:10
    at /home/abdessalem/Desktop/tutum/test/simple-auth-app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:140:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to convert hashedPassword into something that Firestore accepts, such as a Blob. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Blob

Comment: @DougStevenson how can i do that

Comment: I don't know.  That sounds like something you could research by studying the APIs provided by the libraries you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the hash is returns as a readable stream, in which case you can for example hex encode it with:

```
hashedPassword.toString("hex")
```